# Storage for Nodejs bot on Azure?

Tags: azure, botframework

First time using Azure. I have a basic node js bot built with Microsofts Bot Framework, and deployed on Azure. What are my options for storage?

I will most likely just be needing simple key:value storage. Mongodb was my first though but I dont think Azure supports it nativeley.

That said, what are my options for storage on Azure? I usual shy away from MySQL just from preference, but theres no actual reason that wouldnt work either.

Comment: This is really broad and opinion-soliciting, and off topic for StackOverflow. Each storage type you mentioned is very different (discrete storage objects, document store, relational store). This will be dependent on your app, your queries, and other specific needs. There's simply no way to give an answer to this (and note: You haven't even described your use case - you just mentioned making a bot).

Comment: Your right. I was under the impression I was going to be using Mongodb with this project but as far as I can tell Azure does not support it (without special configurations). For the most part, I just need key:value storage.

Comment: Not that it has anything to do with your question, but your assertion regarding Azure not supporting MongoDB is false. Not quite sure where you got that information.

Comment: @DavidMakogon its true, azure does not support mongodb it seems, even though i have opted for mongodb, i see document db everywhere in my bills, in my analytics and everywhere

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at [Azure Table Storage](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-tables/) for a NoSql solution

> Table storage is a key/attribute store with a schemaless design. Because Table storage is schemaless, it's easy to adapt your data as the needs of your application evolve. Access to data is fast and cost-effective for all kinds of applications. Table storage is typically significantly lower in cost than traditional SQL for similar volumes of data.

Comment: This was one of the things that was a tad confusing. So Theres Azure Storage which has Table storage which is a NoSQL db...so how does that compare to Azures DocumentDB? Whats the difference? When should one be used over the other?

Comment: The short answer is that they are both NoSql but Azure Tables is a simple Key/Value store with indexing based on Partition and Row Key.  DocumentDB allows advanced queries but it is less performant and more expensive, so it will depend on your use case.

Comment: As far as ease of use goes, which one is recommended?

Comment: If all you need is key:value use TableStorage

Comment: Well it would need It needs to be searchable, sortable
and have some kind of concept of a user object